Are left-inverses of continuous functions pointwise limits of continuous functions?
Let $f : X \to Y$ be a surjective continuous map and suppose $g: Y \to X$ satisfies $g \circ f = \text{id}_X$. If we have that $Y$ is compact and $X$ and $Y$ are both subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, does it follow that $g$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions?
This is for a project I am working on, where I have been able to identify that, for my purposes, $X, Y$ always have the properties that I described. I am interested to know if it may be possible to make progress with the hypotheses I have given, or if I will have to identify other salient features of the spaces I am studying.
(The Baire category tag is due to the fact that the components of $g$ would be Baire class 1 functions by definition.)

$g$ can be completely arbitrary outside the range of $f$, so certainly no in general.

@DavidGao $f$ is surjective. I will edit that in.

The left inverse property also implies injectivity. On the other hand the result is easily true if X is compact or in general if f is closed or open. In that case f is a homeomorphism.

No. Here is a counterexample with $n = 2$: Let $K = \{r_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}}$ be s.t. each $r_i \in \mathbb{R}$ is a representative of the coset $i \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$. We may further assume $0 \leq r_i \leq 1$ for all $i$. Let $X = (K \times \mathbb{Q}) \cup \{(2, 0)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $Y = S^1$. Fix a homeomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to Y \setminus \{(1, 0)\}$. We now define,
$$f: X \to Y, \; f((x_1, x_2)) = \begin{cases}
\phi(x_1 + x_2)&, \text{if } (x_1, x_2) \in K \times \mathbb{Q}\\
(1, 0)&, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
One observes that $f$ is a continuous bijection, so it admits an inverse $g = f^{-1}: Y \to X$. We note that $g$ is nowhere continuous. Indeed, for any $y \in Y \setminus \{(1, 0)\} \simeq \mathbb{R}$, let $g(y) = (r_i, q)$ for some $i \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ and $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Since every coset in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we may fix $j \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$, $j \neq i$, and for each open neighborhood $O$ around $y$, there exists $y_O \in O$ s.t. the first component of $g(y_O)$ is $r_j$, whence $d(g(y_O), g(y)) \geq |r_j - r_i|$. So $y_O \to y$ but $g(y_O) \not\to g(y)$, whence $g$ is not continuous at $y$. When $y = (1, 0)$, $g(y) = (2, 0)$ is an isolated point in $X$ but $y$ is not isolated in $Y$, whence $g$ is not continuous at $y$ either.
This shows that $g$ is nowhere continuous, but any Baire class $1$ function has its points of continuity a comeager set (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function#Baire_class_1), so $g$ cannot be Baire class $1$. (I would be pretty shocked if $g$ is measurable at all, though I can’t immediately see a way to prove that.)

Thanks, I will read through this soon. I believe that $X$ can be expected to be significantly more regular in the contexts for which I need this result, although I have not yet come up with any good ways to describe how. Do you have any intuitions for additional criteria on $X$ which may be sufficient for the claim to hold? I cannot assume that $X$ is compact in general, or anything which implies that $f$ is a homeomorphism, as suggested by Keplerto.

@J.S. I don’t really know. I would assume in most “reasonable” cases, $g$ should at least be Borel, and probably of a relatively low Baire class. Whether one can ensure it is of Baire class $1$ is beyond me. But if it helps, most things I tried before I came up with the counterexample in the answer has $g$ likely of Baire class $1$. Mostly this is due to $X$ and $f$ not being “excessively disconnected”, in the sense that the set at which $f$ “jumps” (relative to an embedding of $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^d$) is meager.

For a concrete example, I tried $X$ being the Cantor set with right endpoints excluding $1$ removed (equivalently, $X$ is the subset of ${0, 1}^\omega$ containing elements whose tail is not all $1$, except the element that is the constant sequence $1$), and mapped it onto $[0, 1]$ using binary expansions. In this case, $f$ really only “jumps” at $2$-adic rationals, ensuring that $g$ is continuous off a countable set.

Thanks, David. I need to think about it a little more, but the reason for asking this question was that I was able to reduce a requirement that $g$ should be continuous (which is obviously false in general) to one that it should be of Baire class $1$. Thinking a little more, it might actually be the case that the same technique demonstrates that it suffices for $g$ to be of finite Baire class. Should I take your first comment to mean that if the set at which $f$ jumped was meagre, it would be of finite Baire class, or even something better? (If so, I will try to prove this myself.)

@J.S. I don’t know for sure. I’m not an expert in descriptive set theory. It is also hard to formalize what exactly does the set at which $f$ jumps even means, since $f$ is supposed to be continuous. So I’d suggest treating what I said as just purely intuition. Maybe it corresponds to some actual result putting constraints on regularity of $X$, but it’s just a maybe.
